# Dynamically allocated memory for char and for double or int takes the same amout?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    double *data = new double;
    size_t count = 0;
    try {
        while (true) {
            data = new double;
            count++;
        }
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << count;
    }
}
```

This gives output a number like 2*10^8(How much times the loop works, so how much double sized memory frees for ...). Then I change the double to char, and i was expecting that
count must be at last 4 times greater than with double. But i was surprised, the count was like with double(not exactly, cause of RAM usage). I searched a lot and find something about alignment. But, that all is about structures. Can anyone explain why things go this way. And is it possible to set alignment for int or double or char.

Comment: `new` may always occupy larger chunks of memory than the exact size of the aquired type. Its pretty likely for `char` that at least 4 bytes are allocated in reality.

Comment: If that's what you want to test there are easier ways, ways that will eliminate factors that you've included.

Comment: @Gopi there is no new keyword in c

Comment: @Gopi should be `c++` only.

Comment: @Gopi Next time just edit the tags for such obvious case please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ When I saw the question there was a c tag so was just suggesting to remove it

Comment: You can pre-define `new` operator and allocate exactly 1 byte for `char` (plus extra bytes for allocation structure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing a memory allocator there are many different choices to make, depending on which usage you want to optimize.

It's possible to write a memory allocator that will use just slightly more that one byte for each allocated byte, but this would have an impact on the allocation/deallocation time. I can for example think to bitmapped pages allowing a consumption of about 9 bits plus a tiny fraction for each 8-bit char allocated.

Normally memory allocators for performance reasons have instead a minimum block size and any memory request is rounded up to next multiple of that size. Also it's very common to store the size of the allocated memory right before the memory block itself and this also adds up.